# How do I suppress all email notification from cron for particular job?

Tags: shell, cron, io-redirection

I am scheduling the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
(echo open mailserver.nowhere.local 25; sleep 1; echo EHLO; echo quit)\
  | telnet | grep "?Invalid command"

    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
       if [ -r /tmp/sendmail_stopped ]; then
          rm /tmp/sendmail_stopped
          /etc/init.d/sendmail start
          mail -s "sendmail has started back up." me@nowhere.com < /dev/null
       else
           echo "sendmail OK"
       fi
    else
        if [ ! -r /tmp/sendmail_stopped ]; then
            touch /tmp/sendmail_stopped
            /etc/init.d/sendmail stop
        else
            echo "sendmail still not OK"
        fi
    fi
```

like this

`*/5 * * * * root /home/amr/bin/sendmail_alive.sh 2>&1 > /tmp/sendmail_alive.log`

but am still getting email from the `telnet` command.

I've tried a bunch of ways to suppress getting the email that contains the output of the `telnet` command, which is

`Connection closed by foreign host.`

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common mistake, wrong order of redirection, try this:

```
 … sendmail_alive.sh >/tmp/sendmail_alive.log 2>&1
```

It works like this:

1. file descriptor stdout to `/tmp/sendmail_alive.log`
2. file descriptor stderr to the value of stdout (`/tmp/sendmail_alive.log`)

With your order, you first point the stderr where originally was stdout and you get the stderr message "Connection closed by foreign host." there as a result.